# spring data (Hibernate) prevent editing for lazy ManyToOne object with any CascadeType if version be null

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have this object that is transient in hibernate before saving and i got it from rest service:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SWC_EXCEPTION_MAPPING")
public class ExceptionMapping extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EXCEPTION_MAPPING_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "EXCEPTION_MAPPING_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "EXCEPTION_MAPPING_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Supplier supplier;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Date createdDate;
    @Version
    @NotNull
    private Integer version;
}
```

and object value is :
[image]

when I try to save object with spring data with this code I get this error:

code:

```
@Repository
public interface ExceptionMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<ExceptionMapping, Long> {
}

@Service
public class ExceptionMappingServiceImpl implements ExceptionMappingService {

private final ExceptionMappingRepository exceptionMappingRepository;
    private final ExceptionMappingCustomRepository exceptionMappingCustomRepository;

    private final SupplierService supplierService;

    public ExceptionMappingServiceImpl(ExceptionMappingRepository exceptionMappingRepository) {
        this.exceptionMappingRepository = exceptionMappingRepository;
    }


    public void edit(ExceptionMapping exceptionMapping) {
        /* this line */
        exceptionMappingRepository.save(exceptionMapping);
    }
}
```

> Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance
> must be saved before current operation : ExceptionMapping.supplier ->
> Supplier

I know this error was occurred for supplier version that is null because when I set it manually to zero, this error not appear!

my question is that why hibernate check version in `supplier` object while I don't set any CascadeType for that?

i use spring boot with this version : **2.3.12.RELEASE**

Comment: Does Supplier extends your BaseEntity ?

Comment: @Pilpo yes Supplier extends from BaseEntity.

Comment: only way to resolve this problem is using primitive version instead of class :(   `private int version;`

Comment: It's working with int because int cannot be null. You should debug your version number and see yourself the value

Answer (score 0):

Because you said `Supplier extends BaseEntity`, my guess is that `version` is mandatory.

As stated here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic

> A version or timestamp property can never be null for a detached instance.

That's why you get the error.

Comment: No i test your solution but problem exits yet!

Comment: I've edited my answer and you were correct, the problem was elsewhere :)

Comment: ok but as your link , `valid types` contains primitive wrappers like Integer. maybe this case should be handle in hibernate.

Comment: You should not use int type because it will make think hibernate that the entity is already persited while it is not. You might have unexpected behavior in the future as for instance, FK violation. Do yourself a favor and dont use int :)